# Change background image by month

Tags: javascript, css, getelementsbyclassname

I'm trying to change the background image of an element, according to what season it is. I'm getting the following error:

`TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...).style is undefined`

```
var currentTime = new Date();
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
var total = month;

// Summer
if (total >= 6 && total <= 8)
{
document.getElementsByClassName("banner-container").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/homepage-banners/winter-banner.jpg')";
}
// Autumn
else if (total >= 9 && total <= 11)
{
document.getElementsByClassName("banner-container").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/homepage-banners/fall-banner.jpg')";
}
// Winter
else if (total == 12 || total == 1 || total == 2)
{
document.getElementsByClassName("banner-container").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/homepage-banners/winter-banner.jpg')";
}
// Spring
else if (total >= 2 && total <= 6)
{
document.getElementsByClassName("banner-container").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/homepage-banners/spring-banner.jpg')";
}
else
{
document.getElementsByClassName("banner-container").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/homepage-banners/summer-banner.jpg')";
}
```

**Updated script with markup, switching to getElementById:**

```
<div class="custom banner-container">
  <div id="home-banner">
     <div class="dmr-welcome">
        <img src="/dev/images/homepage-banners/dmr-banner1_07.jpg">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

var currentTime = new Date();
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
var total = month;

// Summer
if (total >= 6 && total <= 8)
{
document.getElementById("home-banner").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/homepage-banners/winter-banner.jpg')";
}
// Autumn
else if (total >= 9 && total <= 11)
{
document.getElementById("home-banner").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/homepage-banners/fall-banner.jpg')";
}
// Winter
else if (total == 12 || total == 1 || total == 2)
{
document.getElementById("home-banner").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/homepage-banners/winter-banner.jpg')";
}
// Spring
else if (total >= 2 && total <= 6)
{
document.getElementById("home-banner").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/homepage-banners/spring-banner.jpg')";
}
else
{
document.getElementById("home-banner").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/homepage-banners/summer-banner.jpg')";
}
```

Error is:

TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
document.getElementById("home-banner").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/homepage-banners/fall-banner.jpg')";

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a collection, you have to loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted by elclanrs, getElementsByClassName is not what you're looking for.  It looks to me like you want getElementById.

Also, your javascript is executing before it has a reference to the div you're trying to set the background image on.  Try putting the script at the bottom of the page.

The following worked for me.  Note that I made some changes for file names and image path.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="banner-container" style="width:400px;height:300px;"></div>

<script>
var currentTime = new Date();
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
var total = month;

// Summer
if (total >= 6 && total <= 8)
{
    document.getElementById("banner-container").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/winter.png')";
}
// Autumn
else if (total >= 9 && total <= 11)
{
    document.getElementById("banner-container").style.backgroundImage="url('images/fall.png')";
}
// Winter
else if (total == 12 || total == 1 || total == 2)
{
    document.getElementById("banner-container").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/winter.png')";
}
// Spring
else if (total >= 2 && total <= 6)
{
    document.getElementById("banner-container").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/spring.png')";
}
else
{
    document.getElementById("banner-container").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/summer.png')";
}
</script>

</body> </html>
```

Comment: I changed all instances of getElementsByClassName to getElementById and I still get an error:

TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

    document.getElementById("home-banner").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/homepage-banners/fall-banner.jpg')";

Comment: `document.getElementById()` will only work if those are ids, but I'm betting they are css class names. Try using `document.querySelector('.banner-container')` instead.

Comment: Moving it to the bottom of the page worked. Many thanks.